# In Node.js Create read stream from S3 object or web URL, and PassThrough the read stream to multiple pipes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In a Node.js12.x based Lambda function, I am attempting to

1. Download object from S3
2. Download file from web if object not exists in S3
3. PassThrough the downloaded data regardless of how its arrived to multiple write streams

I tried following

```
var request = require('request');

const readStream = ({ Bucket, Key }) => {

  s3.getObjectMetadata({ Bucket, Key })
    .promise().then(() => {
      return s3.getObject().createReadStream();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.statusCode === 404) {
        return request.get('http://example.com/' + Key);
      }
    });
};

readStream({ ... })
  .pipe(sharp().resize(w, h).toFormat('png'))
  .pipe(writeStream);
```

Above works if the object available in s3, but the catch block doesn't work.

Do I need `await` or a promise on `request.get`?

I also tried following with no luck

```
http.get('http://example.com/' + Key, function(response) { 
    return response;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to create a promise that checks if the object exists in the bucket

```
const isObjectExists = (params) => {
  return s3.headObject(params)
           .promise()
           .then(
             () => true,
             (error) => {
               if (err.statusCode === 404) {
                 return false;
               }
               throw error;
             }
           )}

const awsParams = { Bucket: ..., Key: s3ObjectKey };
const exists = await isObjectExists(awsParams);
```

Next, we need to create a read stream from either s3 or web URL.

Using the deprecated `request` package, since I am not able to get things to work using `http`.

```
let readStream = null;
if (exists) {
    readStream = s3.getObject(awsParams).createReadStream();
} else {
    readStream = request.get('http://example.com/' + s3ObjectKey);
}
```

Pass the just created `readStream` through to process and finally to the upload stream

```
const pass = new PassThrough();

readStream.
  .pipe(sharp().resize(w, h).toFormat('png'))
  .pipe(s3.upload({
    Body: pass,
    Bucket,
    ContentType: 'image/png',
    s3ObjectKey + '-resized'
  }).promise());

const uploadedData = await pass;
```

Add few prerequisites

```
import awS3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';
import { PassThrough } from 'stream'
import * as request from 'request';

const s3 = new awS3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});
```